# Linux - Displaying Memory Usage Live

Tags: c, linux, memory

I'm running [GNU - Screen (4.03.01)](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) so I can have multiple terminals in one, and I'm looking for a good way to display live stats of my memory, so as I do things like compiling, testing programs, etc... I can see how much resources I have left.

I know there is "TOP" the performance monitor... and other similar programs, but I'm not looking for the entire active process list etc... I just want a snapshot of my memory stats that updates for example every 3-5 seconds.

I really appreciate anyone taking the time to help me with this, so thank you!

(for visualization purposes)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Logging as `root` everywhere is a bad habit. Do most things under an ordinary users, and do critical administration commands with e.g. `sudo`

Comment: I know what I'm doing... Thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the combination of  watch which repeats the specified program and displays its output and free which shows current memory usage

```
watch free -m
```

```
free --help

Usage:
 free [options]

Options:
 -b, --bytes         show output in bytes
 -k, --kilo          show output in kilobytes
 -m, --mega          show output in megabytes
 -g, --giga          show output in gigabytes
     --tera          show output in terabytes
 -h, --human         show human-readable output
     --si            use powers of 1000 not 1024
 -l, --lohi          show detailed low and high memory statistics
 -o, --old           use old format (without -/+buffers/cache line)
 -t, --total         show total for RAM + swap
 -s N, --seconds N   repeat printing every N seconds
 -c N, --count N     repeat printing N times, then exit

     --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see free(1).
```

```
watch --help

Usage:
 watch [options] command

Options:
  -b, --beep             beep if command has a non-zero exit
  -c, --color            interpret ANSI color sequences
  -d, --differences[=]
                         highlight changes between updates
  -e, --errexit          exit if command has a non-zero exit
  -g, --chgexit          exit when output from command changes
  -n, --interval   seconds to wait between updates
  -p, --precise          attempt run command in precise intervals
  -t, --no-title         turn off header
  -x, --exec             pass command to exec instead of "sh -c"

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -v, --version  output version information and exit
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Do you know the interval it updates on?

Comment: default is 2 s but you can change it : watch -n 0,1 free -m

Comment: perfect so just pass the parameter in the statement.

Comment: One more question, would you happen to know how to do it for CPU usage as well?

Comment: try one of these http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use valgrind tool [Massif](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif), I haven't tried it, but it seems to be what you are looking for.

To use massif, install valgrind then run:

```
valgrind --tool=massif program argument1 argument2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! but if Linux already comes with a built-in cmd "watch", then I rather use that then install another program.

Comment: @JordanDavis I understand that, but other people who already have `valgrind` might think that it would be better to use than `watch`.

Comment: Yea it would definitely depend on your Linux distro, I don't have valgrind on mine though. I'll plus one your answer still, thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

another fast solution is script like this

```
while true; do 
     free -m
     # any command for CPU stats - i didn't understand - what you really want to see, please clarify - just % of CPU usage ?
     # i think this command should help you.
      ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | paste -sd+ | bc
done
```

Comment: I would add a `sleep 0.5` inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

The other thing you can do is use `htop`. It displays memory usage, CPU usage per core and shows resources used by each process. Really neat but maybe not that detailed as the rest of the answers.